# Why it is not possible to construct a set function that is defined for all sets of real numbers with the following 3 properties?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was reading page 30 of Royden and Fitzpatrick" real analysis ", fourth edition  and the book said: " it is not possible to construct a set function that is defined for all sets of real numbers with the following 3 properties:

1- The measure of an interval is its length.

2- The measure is translation invariant.

3- The measure is countable additive over countable dis-joint unions of sets."  and then the book said as a justification for this that we should look at page 48. here is a part of pg. 48:

> [image]

After that, on the remaining part of the page, the book started to prove thm. 17.

**My question is:**

What is on pg. 48 say that it is not possible to construct a set function that is defined for all sets of real numbers with the previous 3 properties? could anyone explain this to me, please?

Comment: Theorem 17 is precisely that statement. In particular, the statement "contains a subset that fails to be measurable"

Comment: Is it using that measurable means finitely additive? @CharlesHudgins

Comment: The lebesgue measure is the unique measure which has the three properties. Theorem 17 shows that not all sets are lebesgue measurable. The definition of lebesgue measurability should already have been developed in the text by this point. It takes a while to state and there's really only one way to say it. I recommend rereading that section in your book.

Comment: You mean not all **real** sets are Lebesgue measurable @CharlesHudgins ....am I correct?

Comment: That's right. The lebesgue measure is defined on the collection lebesgue measurable sets, which are subsets of the real numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose we have such a function $f$. Now let's use some choice set $\mathcal{C} = \mathcal{C}_E$, where we took $E=[0,1]$.

First, $\{\lambda + \mathcal{C}\}_{\lambda\in \mathbb{Q},\, 0\leq \lambda \leq 1}$ is countable and disjoint, so by property 3 we have

$$
f\left(\bigcup_{\lambda\in\mathbb{Q}, \, 0\leq \lambda \leq 1} (\lambda + \mathcal{C}) \right) = \sum_{\lambda \in \mathbb{Q},\,0\leq \lambda \leq 1} f(\lambda + \mathcal{C}).
$$

Since each point $x\in \mathopen[0,1\mathclose]$ is rationally equivalent to a point $c\in \mathcal{C}$, we have $[0,1] \subset \bigcup_{\lambda\in\mathbb{Q},\, 0\leq \lambda \leq 1} (\lambda + \mathcal{C}) \subset [0,2]$. But $f$ is nondecreasing, so our left hand side lies between $1$ and $2$ by property 1.

Now for the right hand side : by property 2, each $f(\lambda + \mathcal{C})$ is equal to $f(\mathcal{C})$. We have a countable sum of the same real number. Either $f(\mathcal{C})=0$, and then the RHS is zero ; or $f(\mathcal{C})>0$, which implies that the RHS is $+\infty$. Both cases lead to a contradiction.

Comment: Could you please tell me what is $\mathcal{C}$? like giving me an example for it.

Comment: I do not understand why your LHS lies between 1 and 2 ...... could you please clarify this?

Comment: $\mathcal{C}$ is a choice set as defined in the paragraph you posted.

$f$ is nondecreasing : if $A\subset B$ are sets of real numbers, then $A$ and $B\setminus A$ are disjoint, hence $f(B) = f(A) + f(B\setminus A) \geq f(A)$. That explains why our set $X$ with $[0,1] \subset X \subset [0,2]$ has an image $f(X)$ with $1\leq f(X) \leq 2$.

Comment: why the image must be greater than or equal 1?

Comment: could you specify a particular choice for $\mathcal {C}$?... I want to feel concretely what we are doing

Comment: No, $\mathcal{C}$ cannot be constructed and we need the axiom of choice to prove its existence. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set